# I don't know how i can get a value of an select input on livewire 3.4

Tags: php, laravel, inertiajs

That is my blade component named dynamicselect.blade.php

```
<div style="text-align: center">
    <select   wire:model.lazy="selectedValue">
     
        <option value="1" >Opção 1</option>
        <option value="2">Opção 2</option>
        <option value="3">Opção 3</option>
        <option value="4">Opção 4</option>
        <option value="5">Opção 5</option>
        <option value="6">Opção 6</option>
        <option value="7">Opção 7</option>
        <option value="8">Opção 8</option>
        <option value="9">Opção 9</option>
        <option value="10">Opção 10</option>
      </select>
     O valor selecionado é {{ $selectedValue}}

    
</div
```

And this is my class :

```
class DynamicSelect extends Component
{

    public $selectedValue ;
    public function updateSelectedValue(){

        dd($this->selectedValue);
     }
 

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.dynamicselect');
    }
}
```

I already tried wire:model only wire:model.live e etc.

i tried a lot of things including the documentacion of livewire, but don't found any answer

Comment: The `wire:model.lazy` is to listen for the native change events of the fields, for example text fields. Using the `wire:model` for a select field should be fine. Are you hoping for `updateSelectedValue` to be magically executed somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following (might exist other ways but that's one way that should work):

```html
<select wire:model.change="selectedValue">
    {{--  your options --}}
</select>
```

With `wire:model.change`, everytime your select change it will trigger`updatedSelectedValue` function:

```php
public function updatedSelectedValue () {
    dd($this->selectedValue);
}
```